# How to Change Cobalt launch URL and parameter on starboard layer?

Tags: launch, cobalt

Steps to reproduce:

1. Launch Cobalt with different url config
2. It can select url by priority from /3rd/url.url 、command line、profile to default url

Expected result:

1. We can config the launch URL on straboard layer, not just by `cobalt/src/cobalt/browser/application.cc`  getInitialUrl

The Priority may be /3rd/url.ini->commandline->profile->default url

Of course, we don't want to modify the `cobalt/src/cobalt/browser/application.cc`

Comment: The Cobalt Version is master 16

Answer (score 0):

See https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/master/src/starboard/linux/x64x11/main.cc#31 for example how command line arguments are passed to Cobalt. You can implement your overriding logic before calling `Application::Run()`.